# Calculate RGB value at 50% opacity on a white background to match RGB value at 100% opacity

Tags: css, colors, transparency, background-color, alpha-transparency

I'm embedding some Facebook posts in a blog.  I made a nice wrapper for my `iframe` styled with the same background color that Facebook uses: `rgb(240, 242, 245)`.

Now I want to embed an `iframe` in a `div` that has its own background color: `#f2f0fc`.  The gray on light purple is jarring.  Instead of using Facebook's gray, I'd like to darken my `div` by the same amount that Facebook's gray darkens `white`.

Originally I had thought that I could just cut each of Facebook's color components in half and apply a `0.5` opacity, but this clearly is not right.

**Edit**:  My second thought was that because I'm cutting three components in half, it's actually a cubic operation, and thus I must set my opacity to `0.5^3 = 0.125`.  This is much closer, but still a little off.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}

.facebook-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgb(240, 242, 245);
  padding: 1rem;
}
  .facebook-wrapper.transparent {
    background-color: rgba(120, 121, 122, 0.5);
  }
  
  .facebook-wrapper.transparent-2 {
    background-color: rgba(120, 121, 122, 0.125);
  }
  
  .facebook-wrapper > .post {
    max-width: 680px;
    width: 100% !important;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  }

.white {
  padding: 1rem 0;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.alert {
  background-color: #f2f0fc;
  padding: 1rem 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <h2>Opaque</h2><h2>50% transparent</h2><h2>12.5% transparent</h2>
  <div class="white">
    <div class="facebook-wrapper">
      <div class="post">Facebook post!</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="white">
    <div class="facebook-wrapper transparent">
      <div class="post">Facebook post!</div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="white">
    <div class="facebook-wrapper transparent-2">
      <div class="post">Facebook post!</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="alert">
    <div class="facebook-wrapper">
      <div class="post">Facebook post!</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="alert">
    <div class="facebook-wrapper transparent">
      <div class="post">Facebook post!</div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="alert">
    <div class="facebook-wrapper transparent-2">
      <div class="post">Facebook post!</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I calculate the proper component values or the proper opacity values?  In the above rendered snippet, the goal is to get a color/opacity combination that matches the top-left box, but which can be applied to shade the bottom boxes' background color.

Comment: I think it is #767676. You can always screen capture it and use a graphic program to double check it.

Comment: My colored backgrounds won't always be a static value, which is why I need the transparency to work.

Comment: not clear what you want to achieve. What is the expected result in the snippet? left or right?

Comment: The goal is to find either an RGB value or an opacity value such that their combination matches the top-left box, and that can be applied upon the bottom's background color.

Comment: this can probably help you then: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50574620/8620333

Comment: It does not.  That answer is about multiple transparent layers.  I have a single transparent layer.

Comment: *I have a single transparent layer* --> which is a particular case of multiple transparent layer with one opaque layer so it can be helpful if you read the answer fully and understand the math behind it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Termani's comment, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50574524/color-of-stacked-semi-transparent-boxes-depends-on-order/50574620#50574620) gives us the formula:

> ```
> ColorF = (ColorT*opacityT + ColorB*OpacityB*(1 - OpacityT)) / factor
> ```
>
> **ColorF** is our final color. **ColorT**/**ColorB** are respectively the top and bottom colors. **opacityT**/**opacityB** are respectively the top and bottom opacities defined for each color:
>
> The `factor` is defined by this formula `OpacityT + OpacityB*(1 - OpacityT)`.

`OpacityB` in this case is `1` and `ColorB` is `rgb(255, 255, 255)`.

Plug the desired values into the equation and we get:

```
rgb(240, 242, 245) = (ColorT * 0.5 + rgb(255, 255, 255) * 1 * (1 - 0.5)) / (0.5 + 1 * (1 - 0.5))
rgb(240, 242, 245) = (ColorT * 0.5 + rgb(255, 255, 255) * 0.5) / 1
rgb(240, 242, 245) = ColorT * 0.5 + rgb(255, 255, 255) * 0.5
rgb(240, 242, 245) / 0.5 = ColorT + rgb(255, 255, 255)
2 * rgb(240, 242, 245) - rgb(255, 255, 255) = ColorT
rgb(480 - 255, 484 - 255, 490 - 255) = ColorT
rgb(225, 229, 235) = ColorT
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}

.facebook-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgb(240, 242, 245);
  padding: 1rem;
}
  .facebook-wrapper.transparent {
    background-color: rgba(225, 229, 235, 0.5);
  }
    
  .facebook-wrapper > .post {
    max-width: 680px;
    width: 100% !important;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  }

.white {
  padding: 1rem 0;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.alert {
  background-color: #f2f0fc;
  padding: 1rem 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <h2>Opaque</h2><h2>50% transparent adjusted</h2>
  <div class="white">
    <div class="facebook-wrapper">
      <div class="post">Facebook post!</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="white">
    <div class="facebook-wrapper transparent">
      <div class="post">Facebook post!</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="alert">
    <div class="facebook-wrapper">
      <div class="post">Facebook post!</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="alert">
    <div class="facebook-wrapper transparent">
      <div class="post">Facebook post!</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```