# Why does a CSS linear-gradient from color1 to color2 render exactly the same as a linear-gradient from color1 to transparent on a color2 background?

Tags: css, colors, background, linear-gradients

A linear gradient from red to blue can be created with:

```
background: linear-gradient(
              rgb(255,0,0),
              rgb(0,0,255))
```

To create this:

[image]

If you instead faded red to transparent and placed that on a blue background with:

```
background: linear-gradient(
              rgb(255,0,0), 
              rgb(255,0,0,0)),
            rgb(0,0,255);
```

The result is exactly the same:

[image]

In the first example, the center of the image would have RGB values (127.5, 0, 127.5), by linear interpolation.

In the second example, the center of the image is a combination of a partially transparent red (127.5, 0, 0, 0.5) and a solid blue (0, 0, 255). How are these combined to create the same (127.5, 0, 127.5) result as in the first example?

Comment: I've just adjusted your question's formatting for readability (if you disagree with the changes feel free to roll them back), but please note that you left a closing `)` out of your second code sample, following the final `rgb(...)`.

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica Thanks for the edit, it looks good. I don't think a closing `)` is missing because the final `rgb(...)` is not inside the `linear-gradient(...)` scope, it is a separate background rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake in your conclusion. The interpolation of the second gradient will give a center coloration of `(255, 0, 0, 0.5)`  and not `(127.5, 0, 0, 0.5)`

and  `(255, 0, 0, 0.5)` on the top of `(0, 0, 255, 1)` will give `(127.5, 0, 127.5)`

```css
    255*0.5 + 0*(1 - 0.5) = 127.5
    0*0.5   + 0*(1 - 0.5) = 0 
    0*0.5   + 255*(1 - 0.5) = 127.5
```

More details around the math here: [Color of stacked semi-transparent boxes depends on order?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50574524/8620333)