# Combining background colour plus semi-transparent overall to get target colour with CSS

Tags: css, colors

I need some help with combining colours. I have a mostly white layer with the grey shades on it. Since it is fully opaque the layer underneath (which until now has been the correct colour) is obscured. I can make the new layer semi-opaque but of course that affects the colour of the layer underneath. Is there a way of setting the transparency of the new layer so that after it is added the final colour comes out to the right colour?

X + ?% opaque white = #4ea8e9;

(where + means X is underneath the white layer)

Solve for X

---

My best math tells me this colour is not possible. If ? is 50% and the target colour is rgb(78, 168, 233)

```
78 = r * 0.5 + 255 * 0.5 
168 = g * 0.5 + 255 * 0.5
233 = b * 0.5 + 255 * 0.5
```

becomes

```
r = 78/0.5 - 255 = -99   <-- problem
g = 168/0.5 - 255 = 81
b = 233/0.5 - 255 = 211
```

so to make r possible I changed the opacity to 0.3, but that makes g and b impossible

```
r = 78/0.3 - 255 = 5  
g = 168/0.3 - 255 = 81 <-- problem
b = 233/0.3 - 255 = 211 <-- problem
```

My last home is that there is some CSS filter that can operate on the mostly white layer to make the whiteness transparent while keeping the grey shading parts

Comment: if you really want to play with math you may consider changing the blending mode to have another variables. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50582937/8620333

Comment: by the way your math isn't accurate, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50574620/8620333 for the correct formula

Comment: thanks @TemaniAfif I think the error is my maths comes from doing it first with 0.5 and 1-0.5, then switching in 0.3 but not 1-0.3. Anywho, mix-blend-mode is the right answer, I'm just having issues getting it to apply within Leaflet