# In CSS, what is the difference between transparent and inherited color, practically?

Tags: css, background-color

> `transparent` -- Specifies that the color should be transparent. This is default
> `inherit` -- Inherits this property from its parent element.

But practically speaking, I don't see any difference in them. In the following example, both child elements will have `coral` background color.

```html
<div style="background-color: coral">
  <div style="background-color: transparent">
    transparent
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: inherit">
    inherit
  </div>
</div>
```

In which conditions would I get a different result?

Comment: If the parent is coral, and you inherit, it will be coral. Also, if it's transparent, it will be transparent on it's parent, so it will be coral aswell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this example:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1em;
  margin-right: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

div div {
  margin-right: -100%;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: coral">
  <div style="background-color: transparent">
    transparent
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: inherit">
    inherit
  </div>
</div>
```

Transparent elements have *no* background color and you see through them, inheriting elements have a background color (that of their parent). This does make a difference in some situations, like here.

Comment: A good answer to a silly question

Comment: I'm a bit surprised the question comes from someone with 25k unicorn points, but I can understand that the difference isn't obvious in most situations, if you have no expectation of being able to arrange elements in fancy ways as shown above.

Comment: @vals actually, no one talked about the important case where the color itself is transparent and where the difference is clear

Comment: @TemaniAfif You are right, good catch

Comment: @vals I'm glad it was a silly question to you. Not to me.

Comment: @deceze thanks for the example. makes it quite clear.

Answer (score 5):

You can *clearly* see a difference when the color has **transparency** (related: [Color of stacked semi-transparent boxes depends on order?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50574524/8620333))

```css
div {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: rgb(255 127 80 / 50%)">
  <div style="background-color: transparent">
    transparent
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: inherit">
    inherit
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference.

When you set `transparent` then anything behind can be seen not just the parent background. That's the main difference.

```html
<div style="background-color: coral">
  <div style="background-color: transparent; position: relative; z-index: 2">
    transparent
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: inherit; position: relative; z-index: 2">
    inherit
  </div>
  <div style="background: red; height: 100px; float: right; margin-top: -35px; position: relative; z-index: 1">
    difference
  </div>
</div>
```